# How to insert multiple lines in a DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script which I have to add to the page conditionally:

```
<!-- Google Code for Greenwich UC Page Visits Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 659;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "1";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "u8098adasxma";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/659/?label=i70ZCKnX-WAQ39343AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

So, if the parameter of the Url is 456 for example, add the above script to the page. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
var vSpecID = getParameterByName('id');
var vCode = "<!-- Google Code for Greenwich UC Page Visits Conversion Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 659;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "1";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "u8098adasxma";
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/659/?label=i70ZCKnX-WAQ39343AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
    </noscript>";
if (vSpecID == "456") {
    $(".fg").html();
}
<div id="fg" class="fg">
</div>
```

The issue is happening due to the multiple line in the variable. Please help me resolve it.

Comment: You have an error @ if (vSpecID == 456")  - remove "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concate the lines using `+` and `'` instead of `"` because you have another double quotes in the code inside variable and that will cause problems :

```
var vCode = '<!-- Google Code for Greenwich UC Page Visits Conversion Page -->'+
    '<script type="text/javascript">'+
    '/* <![CDATA[ */'+
    'var google_conversion_id = 659;'+
    'var google_conversion_language = "en";'+
    'var google_conversion_format = "1";'+
     .....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` Not sure what line...

Comment: You're welcome, I think you can see the number of line in right side of developper console.

Comment: I had to use `.text()` and that worked but the source code is not displaying the code.

Comment: Yes but it added to the page directly... I might have to use `jQuery(body).append()`

Comment: Ok you can try `jQuery(body).append()` that will add the code in the end of your body, that may help.